# Shadow at the bottom of recycler view when there are more items to be displayed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to show a shadow at the bottom of my recycler view when there are more items to be displayed. I don't want the shadow to be out of the view. I want it inside.
This is what i have[recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5yqV.png)
The user will not know that he can scroll for more options, and that is why I want to add shadow at the bottom. Something like this:
[recyclerView with shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZhqT.png)
Not soo good with photo editing but you get the point.

Comment: show us some screenshots of expected and current result. Also what you have tried please let us know by some code.

Comment: Why not simply enable the scrollbars? Then the user sees if there is more content.

Comment: @Ridcully Because the designers want shadows

Comment: Yeah, those "designers" we all fear :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"` to your RecyclerView in the XML